# Unable to dynamically change URL filters chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my chrome extension code:

background.js:

```
var blockedUrls = function () {
    if (localStorage.blocks) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.blocks).urls
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function () {
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {urls: blockedUrls()},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "HintBlockRequest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Block URLS",
  "background":  {
    "scripts": [ "background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Hint Block Request"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon_16.png",
    "48": "icon_48.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

The goal is that when localStorage is empty - filter empty list. Then, when I fill the localStorage with this:

```
localStorage.setItem('blocks', JSON.stringify({urls: ['https://*/*css*','http://*/*css*']}))
```

URL filters should be updated.

Working code is:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function () {
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {urls: ['https://*/*css*','http://*/*css*']},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

(without the function)

The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'urls': Expected 'array' but got 'function'.
    at validate (extensions::schemaUtils:34:13)
    at WebRequestEventImpl.addListener (extensions::webRequestEvent:80:3)
    at WebRequestEvent.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as addListener] (extensions::utils:138:26)
    at chrome-extension://gccoagdpplpkngajecblejkpopiojofd/background.js:13:35
```

Comment: Which is the exact line you have your problem at?

Comment: background.js:13

Comment: hi! did you solve this? i'm in a similar issue... not sure if the function "blockedUrls()" does his work dynamically in urls param :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blockedUrls` is a `function` returning an array, but you missed to call it. So instead of

```
{urls: blockedUrls},
```

you will need

```
{urls: blockedUrls()},
```

Comment: Thanks.Now I'm not getting the error, however, when I'm trying to load one of the extension's resources, I get flgfkoakmmpjlmmkdelkhhpiimiiocke is blocked
Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
Try disabling your extensions.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT for example, when trying to hit: chrome-extension://flgfkoakmmpjlmmkdelkhhpiimiiocke/icon.png

Comment: @AdiOhana probably you do not have blocks in localStorage yet.

Comment: Correct. I still don't have blocks in localStorage. but I still should be able to hit extension resources, no?

Comment: @AdiOhana actually I only know the answer to your question, that is, you did not call the function returning the array. Since I have not worked on browser extensions yet, I do not know the answer to the second question. I think the best would be to accept my answer as it solved the initial problem and ask a separate question about the new problem. Then people more eloquent with browser extensions will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand what is the issue with the extension

Comment: @AdiOhana you are welcome,  let's hope you will find out the answer easily.